# Hide Markers on Click with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am building a search form using Google Maps Javascript V3 API. I would like to add some filters that will hide certain types of markers on the map when clicked. The markers to hide are represented with

```
locations[i][11] == 'Other'
```

### HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="hideOtherMarkers">Hide Other Markers</a>
```

### JavaScript:

```
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 48.509532, lng: -122.643852}
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
  var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations_array); ?>;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {

        var content = '';
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByClassName('hideOtherMarkers')[0], 'click', function() {
        if (locations[i][11] == 'Other') {
            marker.setVisible(false); // maps API hide call
        }
    });

  } 

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

When I click the link nothing fires, verified with alerts. I also tried google.maps.event.addListener (without Dom) with no success.

Comment: i is left set to `locations.length`.  `locations[locations.length][11]` is undefined.  undefined is never going to be equal to 'Other'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by geocodezip this approach will not work, because `i` will always point behind the end of `locations`.  Additionally this would hide at best 1 marker (the last marker that has been created).

Possible approach:

Store the visible-state of the markers in a MVCObject:

map-options:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 48.509532, lng: -122.643852}
    //that's the property where we store the state
    visibility:new google.maps.MVCObject
  };
```

inside the loop, after the creation of `marker`:

```
//when the state is not set yet, set it
if(typeof map.get('visibility').get(locations[i][11])==='undefined'){
  map.get('visibility').set(locations[i][11],true);
}
//bind the visible-property of the marker to the state
marker.bindTo('visible',map.get('visibility'),locations[i][11]);
```

add the listener(outside of the loop):

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(
   document.getElementsByClassName('hideOtherMarkers')[0], 
   'click', 
    function() {
       //simply set the desired property of the MVCObject to false
       map.get('visibility').set('Other',false);
    });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5L2392mL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5L2392mL/)

Comment: Thanks this worked. Seems to add quite a bit of initial load time though?

Comment: How can I do this with a boolean value also?

Comment: you can't. The binding requires a observable value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a different solution that would allow to filter based on boolean values?