# Toggle Show/Hide Google Circle with 1 button

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have created the circle around the center of the stated position in Google Map. I want to toggle it with one button to show or hide the circle/radius which I could not found from the references I looked up on internet.

References: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes
[Hide Markers on Click with Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918489/hide-markers-on-click-with-google-maps-api)
[show/hide circle on google maps javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683688/show-hide-circle-on-google-maps-javascript-api)

Codes:

```
<button class="button-red pure-button" onclick="toggleRadius()">

var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 1.3420894594991328, lng: 103.83490918886719},
    });

    var ntuc = {lat: 1.32805676, lng: 103.9216584};

    var ntucCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: ntuc,
        radius: 5000, // in metres
        visible: false
      });

      ntucCircle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

  }
```

I have tried 3 ways to toggle the Google Circle but to no avail.

1st Method:

```
  function toggleRadius() {
    ntucCircle.set('opacity', ntucCircle.get('opacity') ? null : 0.35);
  }
```

2nd Method:

```
  function toggleRadius() {
    ntucCircle.setMap(ntucCircle.getMap() ? null : map);
  }
```

3rd Method:

```
  function toggleRadius() {
    if (ntucCircle.getMap() != null) {
        ntucCircle.setMap(null);
    } else {
        ntucCircle.setMap(map);
    }
  }
```

I am not sure what went wrong. I appreciate any form of help given and hopefully one is able to answer my question - toggle Google Circle using 1 button.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addMarker is not defined`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, i have updated the code according to mcve. thank you for the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question and here's the solution.

```
<button class="button-red pure-button" onclick="toggleRadius()">

var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 1.3420894594991328, lng: 103.83490918886719},
});

var ntuc = {lat: 1.32805676, lng: 103.9216584};

var ntucCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: ntuc,
    radius: 5000, // in metres
  });

  ntucCircle.setMap(null);


  function toggleRadius() {
    ntucCircle.setMap(ntucCircle.getMap() ? null : map);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code:

```
function toggleRadius() {
  ntucCircle.setMap(ntucCircle.getMap() ? null : map);
}
```

I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined` because `ntucCircle` is local to the `initMap` function, not in the global context (where HTML click handler functions are required to be).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ek29z0Ln/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// global variables
var map;
var ntucCircle;
var markers = [];

function toggleRadius() {
  ntucCircle.setMap(ntucCircle.getMap() ? null : map);
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 1.3420894594991328,
      lng: 103.83490918886719
    },
  });

  var ntuc = {
    lat: 1.32805676,
    lng: 103.9216584
  };

  // initialize the global variable
  ntucCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: ntuc,
    radius: 5000, // in metres
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<button class="button-red pure-button" onclick="toggleRadius()">toggle</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```